# flex skin problem

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

how can i add flex  style reference in flex skin like below example whenever i add this code in my flex file in f:style tag it remove all skin styles how i can set  SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin thankss

```
skinClass:ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
component.setStyle('skinClass', spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin);
```

For more information read up on using the [setStyle method to apply programmatic Skins](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_3.html)